Biber does't work in VS code
I use VS code to run miktex. But I always encounter errors becuase of failing of biber.
I have searched online that for window 10, if I want to use biber to compile in cmd, I need to add "--winunicode" before the file name. And it does work.
But how do I make the adjustment in VS code? Is there a way to set it in JSON?
